# Яндекс карты API как получить zoom для геокоординат

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите как можно передать зум в инициализацию мапы из полученного геоообъкта. Проблема заключается что карта прогружается с изначально установленным зумом, а потом второй раз прогружается уже с bounds. Как можно получить зуум из геообъекта для мапы и инициализировать туда его?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init(){ 

        ymaps.geocode('Россия, Чебоксары', {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            var coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();
            var bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');
            firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
            firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());

            var myMap;
            myMap = new ymaps.Map("block-map", {
                center: coords, zoom: 10
            });

            myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
            myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {position: {top: 15, left: 15}});
            myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
            myMap.setBounds(bounds, {checkZoomRange: true});

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: А зачем?
Если у вас будет одна единственная метка (как сейчас по коду), то просто задайте сразу крупный масштаб и не меняйте bounds карты после добавления геообъекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init(){ 

        ymaps.geocode('<%=adres%>', {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            var coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();
            var bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');
            firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
            firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());

            var myMap;
            myMap = new ymaps.Map("block-map", {
                center: coords, bounds: bounds, checkZoomRange: true
            });

            myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
            myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {position: {top: 15, left: 15}});

            myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
            //myMap.setBounds(bounds, {checkZoomRange: true});

        });
    }
</script>
```